# Counting the number of parallel threads in a server

Tags: linux, multithreading, parallel-processing

Following is an output of the "lscpu" command in a server machine.

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                32
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-31
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    8
Socket(s):             2
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 45
Stepping:              7
CPU MHz:               1200.000
BogoMIPS:              5188.69
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              20480K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-31
```

How many threads can be executed in parallel on this machine? what will be the formula to calculate this number with the above parameters?

Comment: 32. You can see it in two places: `CPU(s)` and `NUMA node(s) * Socket(s) * Core(s) per socket * Thread(s) per core`.

Comment: but it says 2 threads per core and 8 cores per socket

Comment: And 2 sockets. 2 * 8 * 2 = 32.

Comment: okay. DO I have to consider hyperthreading in addition to this?

Comment: "Thread(s) per core" parameter is taking account of hyperthreading. If you DON'T want to consider hyperthreading, don't multiply by it.

Comment: Thanks. This says it has only one numa node, does that mean it has only one memory which is common to each cpu in the node? so basically it acts as a symmetric multiprocessor inside this node?